# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript

i can push an item to prices array when invoked in console but not when i click the button..

```
<input type="text" id = "currentPrice">
<button type="button" id = "calcButton">Show</button>

var Newchart = function () {
    this.prices = []
}
Newchart.prototype.addNewprice = function () {
    var priceValue = +(document.getElementById('currentPrice').value);
    this.prices.push(priceValue);
    console.log('hello')
}
var c = new Newchart();
var el = document.getElementById("calcButton");
el.addEventListener("click", c.addNewprice, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the context is `window` in the callback's call, not your `Newchart` instance.

A solution is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
el.addEventListener("click", c.addNewprice.bind(c), false);
```

The MDN has a documentation regarding this problem : [The value of this within the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler).

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate. If somebody finds a good QA, I'll close.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: @FelixKling It's a little too general but it will do. Closed. I let my answer which is focused on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

issue of `this` variable

```
el.addEventListener("click", c.addNewprice, false);
```

**Edit - suggested by @dystroy**

In your case `this` points to the `window` not the `class` or the `function`.

Comment: No `this` isn't the `event`.

Comment: @dystroy, OK then please let me know, what exactly addEventListner is called?

Comment: Simply read my answer